# replace select table by an update

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have an intermediate table:

**text_mining_molecule**

```
|text_mining_id| molecule_id |
| -------------| ----------  |
|  ID          |  ID         |
```

and two other tables:

**Table Molécules:**

```
id  | main_name | others …
--- | --------- | ------
1   | caféine   | others …
```

**Table jsonTextMining:**

```
id | title  | molecule_name                       | others …
---|------- |-------------------------------------|------
1  | title1 | colchicine, cellulose, acid, caféine| others …
```

`text_mining_molecule` need to be inserted when select a choice in a list with ID's from 2 others tables `json_text_mining` and `molecule`.

Actually there is a dropdown that already insert all rows from `json_text_mining` to `text_mining` when choose a score under 4.

```
INSERT INTO text_mining (id, solrid, originalpaper, annotatedfile, title, keyword, importantsentence, version, klimischscore, moleculename, synonymname, validation)
            SELECT id, solrid, originalpaper, annotatedfile, title, keyword, importantsentence, version, klimischscore, molecule_name, synonym_name, validation
            FROM json_text_mining WHERE klimischscore < 4
```

This works but i need `text_mining_molecule` to be filled also with related ID's so i have also this part of code :

```
SELECT s.id, m.id
          FROM (SELECT id, regexp_split_to_table(molecule_name,', ') AS m_name
          FROM json_text_mining) AS s, molecule m
          WHERE m.main_name = s.m_name;
```

How can i update `text_mining_molecule` table directly with an `insert` instead a `select` ?

Comment: some FK?.. what's the relation between text_mining_molecule and s.id, m.id?..

Comment: `json_text_mining` is a temp table where all articles are in wait to be validated. When someone click on a validation button the `json_text_mining` article is copyed to `text_mining` table but the relation in intermediate table is not there

Comment: so then you need insert, not update?..

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 0):

use CTE. eg if `text_mining_molecule.molecule` references `molecule.id`, would be smth like:

```
with c as (
SELECT s.id sid, m.id mid
          FROM (SELECT id, regexp_split_to_table(molecule_name,', ') AS m_name
          FROM json_text_mining) AS s, molecule m
          WHERE m.main_name = s.m_name
)
update text_mining_molecule t
set sid = c.sid
from c
where t.molecule = c.mid
```